# Pass localStorage value into service angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I make a controller to take or set photo and then upload with ngcordova plugin.

Is it possible to convert into service so I could use every time calling ng-click="takePhoto"?

This is my controller:

```
.controller('CameraCtrl', function ($scope, $cordovaCamera, $ionicLoading, $localstorage) {
    //$scope.data = { "ImageURI" :  "Select Image" };
    $scope.takePicture = function() {
      var options = {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URL,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
      };
      $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(
        function(imageData) {
            $scope.picData = imageData;
            $scope.ftLoad = true;
            $localstorage.set('fotoUp', imageData);
            $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Foto acquisita...', duration:500});
        },
        function(err){
            $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Errore di caricamento...', duration:500});
            })
      }
})
```

I'll try by myself but when I put into services.js return this error:

```
ReferenceError: Camera is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem persists? Did you try to debug in real device? Usually this error happens when you are testing on a browser on your pc or even an emulator. I've faced the same problem days ago and the reason was that my phone needed to be updated. Also, if you have installed any other app that uses the camera, some errors might be raised.